# React Material UI Tooltip on List won't stay open on hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm implementing a Material UI `List` which maps over a list of users and generates a new `ListItem` for each of them. Each of these `ListItem`s are an image of the user's profile and what I want to accomplish is that when you hover over said image, a tooltip with the user's info appears.

This is working just fine. However, I can't figure out why I'm having issues trying to get the `Tooltip` within each `ListItem` to actually remain open when hovering over it. Currently, as soon as it leaves the image, the tooltip gets removed (which, again, I don't want happening).

From the documentation it seems like using `interactive` on the `Tooltip` component should fix this behaviour, but it's just not working for me...

Stripping some internal logic aside, this is essentially what I'm talking about:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  Tooltip
} from '@material-ui/core'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import classNames from 'classnames'

const styles = theme => ({
  flex: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  defaultIconContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'orange', // use theme global variable
    width: '40px',
    height: '40px'
  },
  defaultIconTextContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    padding: '0 !important'
  },
  defaultIconText: {
    color: theme.palette.text.contrastText
  },
  thumbnailImage: {
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    margin: '0 5px 10px'
  }
})

type Props = {
  type: ?string,
  usersList: Array
}

class HelpUsers extends Component<Props> {
  defaultProps = {
    type: 'thumbnail',
    usersList: []
  }

  thumbnail = ({ user, classes }) => (
      <ListItem
        key={user.id}
        disableGutters
        className={classNames(
          classes.defaultIconContainer,
          classes.thumbnailImage
        )}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${user.profilePicture})`
        }}
      >
        <Tooltip
          title={
            <React.Fragment>
              <div>{user.name}</div>
              <div>{user.title}</div>
              <div>{user.company}</div>
              <div>p: {user.mobilePhone}</div>
              <div>c: {user.workPhone}</div>
              <div>e: {user.email}</div>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
          interactive
        >
          <div style={{ opacity: 0 }}>{user.name}</div>
        </Tooltip>
      </ListItem>
  )

  render() {
    const { usersList, classes } = this.props

    if (this.props.type === 'thumbnail') {
      return (
        <List className={classes.flex}>
          {
            usersList.map(user => this.thumbnail({ user, classes }))
          }
        </List>
      )
    }

    return <div>Hello</div>
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(HelpUsers)
```

And here's a userList example:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test Name 1',
    profilePicture: 'https://fillmurray.com/200/300',
    workPhone: '123-123-1231',
    mobilePhone: '456-456-4564',
    email: 'test1@test.com',
    company: 'Company Name',
    title: 'Senior Something'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test Name 2',
    profilePicture: 'https://fillmurray.com/100/300',
    workPhone: '123-123-1231',
    mobilePhone: '456-456-4564',
    email: 'test2@test.com',
    company: 'Company Name',
    title: 'Senior Something'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test Name 3',
    profilePicture: 'https://fillmurray.com/200/400',
    workPhone: '123-123-1231',
    mobilePhone: '456-456-4564',
    email: 'test3@test.com',
    company: 'Company Name',
    title: 'Senior Something'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Test Name 4',
    profilePicture: 'https://fillmurray.com/400/400',
    workPhone: '123-123-1231',
    mobilePhone: '456-456-4564',
    email: 'test4@test.com',
    company: 'Company Name',
    title: 'Senior Something'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Test Name 5',
    profilePicture: 'https://fillmurray.com/400/500',
    workPhone: '123-123-1231',
    mobilePhone: '456-456-4564',
    email: 'test5@test.com',
    company: 'Company Name',
    title: 'Senior Something'
  }
]
```

Any and all help will be much appreciated!

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

**EDIT**:

I actually just created the following codesandbox and for some reason it IS working properly here, but not in my application... I might have to look at some levels up to see why this is affecting the behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/00x4z00040

Comment: `interactive` means that if you hover over the tooltip it will not close, not that it will not close at all.

Comment: @o4ohel Yes, I'm aware. That's what I want to accomplish. I want for it not to close when hovering over the tooltip. But it's closing in every single scenario, immediately.

Comment: you probably need to add a `leaveDelay={2000}` or however much time is needed for user to move mouse over the tooltip.

Comment: I think the reason it's working on your codesandbox example is b/c there is no "space" between the list element and the tooltip element so the cursor goes over the tooltip immediately. To be safe add the `leaveDelay` prop (see my comment above).

Comment: @o4ohel Yeah, initially that was my thought as well so I had already tested it, but the only thing that happens is that it remains open for 2 seconds, but it will close right after that. So if you go straight from the `ListItem` to the `Tooltip` it will still close it after the 2 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing... Seems like I was working with an older version of Material UI on my app, which is why codesandbox worked. I decided to change the version to the latest (`3.5.1`) and problem solved... Leaving it here because it could maybe somehow help/remind people to check versions as well.